# Using a variable from outside SQL Procedure in c# asp.net and Ambiguous Column Name

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, declare

im pretty new in sql coding and i couldent find a solution on internet, heres my code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GET_SAMEDATE (@FileName VARCHAR(50))
AS
    /* SET NOCOUNT ON */
    SELECT Hash
    FROM   Beamer.PackageDetailFile A(NOLOCK)
           INNER JOIN(SELECT FileName,
                             MAX(Date) MaxDate
                      FROM   Beamer.PackageDetailFile(NOLOCK)
                      GROUP  BY FileName)B
             ON B.FileName = A.FileName
                AND A.Date = B.MaxDate
    WHERE  FileName = @FileName
```

what i want to do is i want to compare the FileName with the filename i obtain from a c# class

And im also getting "Ambiguous column name 'FileName' "

*** ambigious column name is resolved but still i cannot get the FileName from the other class to compare if they have the same filename

the c# code

```
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString);

 SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("dbo.GET_SAMEDATE", myConnection );
 myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
 try
 {
    myConnection.Open();
    SqlDataReader sdr = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

    while (sdr.Read())       
    {                   
        string h = (string)sdr.GetString(0);                     

        if (hash != h)
        {
           exists = true;
        }

       sdr.Read();
    }
```

Comment: Make sure you dispose your sqlConnection, sqlDataReader, and sqlCommand objects. The [using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) statement makes this very easy to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to specify the table prefix in the `WHERE` clause. You don't need the join on the sub query with `GROUP BY` anyway though. It can be done much simpler.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GET_SAMEDATE (@FileName VARCHAR(50))
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES Hash
    FROM   Beamer.PackageDetailFile
    WHERE  FileName = @FileName
    ORDER  BY Date DESC
```

Comment: im dont want to order them by date, i was aiming to get the files which has the same filename as the filenames in another class and also get the one which has the latest date.

Comment: @tipi - The query in my answer has the same semantics as the one in your question and should return the same thing. If the semantics of the original query are wrong provide example data and desired results not just the broken query.

Comment: okay i get it now, but the @FileName  want to compare the FileName, i want to send that data from my other class:

Comment: i have edited the original post, if you could check the rest of my code :/

Answer (score 1):

In your `WHERE` clause you should specify which table the `FileName` is coming from A or B:

```
WHERE  FileName = @FileName
```

so either:

```
WHERE  A.FileName = @FileName
```

or

```
WHERE  B.FileName = @FileName
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the parameter value before you execute the stored procedure.

```
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileName", hash)
```

You can also simplify your stored procedure as Martin Smith suggested in his answer.

You haven't included all of the code but make sure you dispose your sqlConnection, sqlDataReader, and sqlCommand objects. You can use the "Using" statement to accomplish this.